# How to save query result in string

Tags: android

Given below is my sqlite query. How will I save result in string? I want to save query result in string. Below is my query which give result in sqlite editor, but I want to get it in code.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(Fare)  FROM jobs WHERE timeweek  > '2014/03/24 20:20'

private static final String KEY_COMPID = "_compid";
private static final String KEY_TIMEJOB = "timejob";
private static final String KEY_TIMEWEEK = "timeweek";  

private static final String KEY_PICK = "pick";
private static final String KEY_DEST = "dest";
private static final String KEY_FARE = "fare";
                        + KEY_TIME + " TEXT" + ")";
    String CREATE_COMPLETED_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS
            + "(" + KEY_COMPID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TIMEJOB
            + " TEXT,"   + KEY_PICK + " TEXT," + KEY_DEST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FARE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TIMEWEEK + " DateTime" + ")";

public String  totaljobsaearnafterlogin() {
int cnt;

String selectQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(Fare)  FROM" + 
    TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " WHERE " +KEY_TIMEWEEK+"  > '2014/03/24 20:10'";    

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list


//cursor.moveToFirst();
cnt= cursor.getCount();

cursor.close();

db.close();
```

Comment: What you mean? You want to save the select result?

Comment: yes i want to store  int cnt; cnt= cursor.getCount();

Comment: number of row effected by query

Answer (score 0):

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count ,SUM(Fare) as fare  FROM" + 
    TABLE_COMPLETED_JOBS + " WHERE " +KEY_TIMEWEEK+"  > '2014/03/24 20:10'";   


Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
cnt= cursor.getCount();
if(cnt > 0) {
   int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("count"));

   int fareSum = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("fare"));

   String result = count + " " + fareSum;
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: in my table no index for count

Comment: I changed the query, SELECT COUNT(*) as count, this is how you select the COUNT function result as a variable count

Comment: when i run this query in sqlite editor it will show me 6.5 in ruturn SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(Fare)  FROM jobs WHERE timeweek  > '2014/03/24 20:20'    how i will get same result in my code???

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: when i run this query in sqllite editor it will give me result 6.5 in return
SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(Fare)  FROM jobs WHERE timeweek  > '2014/03/24 20:20'
my question is how i will execute same query in code and get result in string?

Comment: I just showed you, the "result" variable will store the result. You can do Log.v("TAG", result); to print it to console.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate the rows and get each element.

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
String string = "";

if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
   string += "Count: " + cursor.getString(1) + "\n";
   string += "Fare:  " + cursor.getString(2) + "\n";

}
```